# Make Custom Post Archive in Ascending Order

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to make my custom post type archive page reverse the display order, and want to make it ASCENDING.  This is my code:

```
<?php   

    while ( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();
?>

   --MY CODE--

<?php } ?>
```

I tried putting query_posts('order=asc'); before the while loop, but this caused my loop to draw from the regular posts, not my custom post type.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: can you post what you've tried so far apart from just query_post('order=asc').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple query here. Don't use `query_posts`, never ever. Use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You should do

```
<?php

$args= array(
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'post_type' => 'NAME OF YOUR CPT'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :$the_querythe_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your ordering to the existing query. The way you did it overwrote the query. Try this:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string.'&order=ASC' );
while( have_posts() ): the_post();
  // rest of your code
endwhile;
```